# MySQL fetch_array not working?

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have 2 tables in my database - link and suggestions.

This is how my code looks. In the first code, I pull out suggestions from the DB and show them, but when I try to show the videolink from the other table, it does not work.

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$from = "suggestions";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$from."` WHERE `ID` = '". $_GET['ID'] ."'");
$vis = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

echo ("TITLE: <br />");
echo ("".$vis['title']."");
echo ("<br /> <br /> SUGGESTION: <br />");
echo ("".$vis['suggestion']."");

$from2 = "link";
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$from2."` WHERE `ID` = '". $_GET['ID'] ."'");
$vis2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
echo ("<br /> <br /> LINK:");
echo ("".$vis2['videolink']."");
```

Comment: define: **it does not work**

Comment: It showcases nothing. It shows the title "LINK" as I wrote in my echo, but it won't fetch the link itself called "videolink". It doesnt show it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your query ($sql2) is failing and therefore not producing a query resource, but instead producing FALSE.

To reveal what your dynamically generated query looks like and reveal the errors, try this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql2) or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
```

The error message will guide you to the solution, which from your comment below is related to using ORDER BY on a field that doesn't exist in the table you're SELECTing from.

Comment: It gives me this error.

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Project Challenger\seting.php on line 14

Is this a syntax error?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource boolean given in php error on server if you get this error : please select all privileges on your server. u will get the answer..

Comment: I dont understand this. I am new into MYSQL and Php. Can you reformulate your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Check your sql string ...

try

```
$id = $_GET['id'];


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `suggestions` WHERE `ID` ='$id'");
```

Comment: The arrays from suggestions is showcasing, not the ones from the link.

I tried adding this:

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM suggestions WHERE ID ='$id'");

This doesn't change it. Nothing shows yet. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with that code. All someone has to do is go to

```
yourpage.php?ID=1;DELETE FROM suggestions
```

and your table would be deleted. And you don't have to wrap your `echo` in parentheses. 
Otherwise, try the SQL queries directly in phpMyAdmin and see what errors it throws back.

Comment: Don't worry, it's only on my local server right now. I am learning MySQL as I am building a simple website, it's not going public juuuust yet.

Also, I removed the parantheses in echo, it didnt change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Are there more than one link for one id? Maybe you could try this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "LINK: ". $row['videolink'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and give the error it gives

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$from = "suggestions";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$from."` WHERE `ID` = '". $_GET['ID'] ."'");
if($sql){
$vis = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo ("TITLE: <br />");
echo ("".$vis['title']."");
echo ("<br /> <br /> SUGGESTION: <br />");
echo ("".$vis['suggestion']."");
}
else
echo mysql_error();

$from2 = "link";
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$from2."` WHERE `ID` = '". $_GET['ID'] ."'");
if($sql2){
$vis2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
echo ("<br /> <br /> LINK:");
echo ("".$vis2['videolink']."");
}
else
echo mysql_error();
?>
```

Comment: It gives no error. It is the same as before, no link is shown. :(

Answer (score 0):

## debugging

I changed your whole file. Please post in comments what gets outputted after you run this

```
<?php
define('DEBUG',1);
include('config.php');

if (!DEBUG) {
  $q = 'SELECT * FROM suggestions WHERE `ID` = '.abs((int)$_GET['ID']);
  $res = mysql_query($q);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC);
  echo nl2br(sprintf("TITLE: \n%s\n\nSUGGESTION:\n%s",$row['title'],$row['suggestion']));
  $q = 'SELECT * FROM link WHERE `ID` = '.abs((int)$_GET['ID']);
  $res = mysql_query($q);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC);
  echo nl2br(sprintf("\n\nLINK:%s",$row['videolink']));
} else {
  ob_start();
  // my debugging operation
  echo 'DESCRIBE `link` RETURNS schema: link (ID, videotitle, videolink)'.PHP_EOL;
  $q = 'SELECT * FROM link';
  $res = mysql_query($q);
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) print_r($row);
  echo '<pre>'.ob_get_clean().'</pre>';
}
```

I hope this starts turning out some results

Comment: This is the output 


boolean false
Array
(
    [Field] => ID
    [Type] => int(11)
    [Null] => NO
    [Key] => PRI
    [Default] => 
    [Extra] => auto_increment
)
Array
(
    [Field] => videotitle
    [Type] => text
    [Null] => NO
    [Key] => 
    [Default] => 
    [Extra] => 
)
Array
(
    [Field] => videolink
    [Type] => text
    [Null] => NO
    [Key] => 
    [Default] => 
    [Extra] => 
)

Comment: I think I have found a problem. This is just a hypothesis but it seems that we are passing a string to the `WHERE` clause in the query. The field `ID` is being passed a string `"'.$_GET['ID'].'"`. Try to run the query removing the double quotes from that. I'll edit my code so you can see it and add a comment on the problem. If this works, don't forget to remove the debugging code

Comment: this is ridiculous! I'll add some more debugging code to start narrowing the problem down. It'll take before I get set up so please be patient

Comment: I rewrote the whole thing, as before, please let me know what gets outputted, and if you have any questions you know what to do